# Coin flip method advice

Tags: java, string, random, methods

I was assigned to create a method that simulates flipping a coin. I think my code here is pretty solid, only I can't get it to show a series of results after n number of flips. So instead of showing HTHHHTTTHTT, I'm only getting H or T.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println((flipCoin(2, 10)));

}
    public static String flipCoin(int chance, int numFlips) {
        String result = "";
        Random rando = new Random();
        chance = rando.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < numFlips; i++) {
            if (chance % 2 == 0) {
                result = "H";
            }
            else {
                result = "T";
            }
            numFlips++;
        }
        return result;
}
```

Comment: print the result while flipping (in `for` loop), if you want to keep it for caller method (main) then append the flips to the result String or return an array or list

Comment: How do I append the results to the String?

Comment: Never use something like `nextInt()` on a `Random` followed by `%2` (or `%n` in general). Just use `nextInt(2)` (resp. `nextInt(n)`) to get the right integer in the first place. Or just `nextBoolean()`. The “advanced” solution is `String result = rando.ints(numFlips, 0, 2).mapToObj(i -> i==0? "H": "T").collect(Collectors.joining());`

Answer (score 3):

You iterate over `numFlips` times, but in each iteration, you call either `result = "H";` or `result = "T";`. This sets the value of `result` to either `"H"` or `"T"`.

Instead, you should append it. You can do this by calling `result += "T";`, or you can use a `StringBuilder` and call `stringBuilder.append("T");`.

Comment: Added the += to H and T but know its either printing HHHHHHHHHHH or TTTTTTTTTT

Comment: @Battle You only generate *one* random number, before the loop, and use it over and over again to pick "H" or "T". You need to generate a new random number each time around the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You have to move random generation into the loop so the chance is recalucalted for each throw. Something like

```
public static String flipCoin(int numFlips) {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");
            Random rando = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < numFlips; i++) {
                if (rando.nextInt() % 2 == 0) {
                    result.append("H");
                }
                else {
                     result.append("T");
                }
            }
            return result.toString();
    }
```

That way you won't get 10 of the same.

Plus your `int chance` argument in

```
flipCoin(int chance, int numFlips)
```

is redudant, beacuse you override it with

```
chance = rando.nextInt();
```

later in the code.

Comment: ok I see, I've figured it out it works fine now thank you for the assistance